# Composite Controls JQuery and Apostrophes being encoded

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, custom-server-controls, composite-controls

I am having an issue where composite child controls are encoding strings to HTML. I have a child control button that is set like so:

```
b.OnClientClick = "$('#pic').rotateRight();";
```

the trouble with this is when the composite control is rendered to a web page the source displays:

```
onclick="$(&#39;#pic&#39;).rotateRight();" />
```

Obviously I don't want ', I want to have apostrophes ' , nothing I seem to try works, it always comes out encoded. This is required to get some basic jquery functionality working. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution

http://avinashsing.sunkur.com/2010/10/29/asp-net-html-encoding-attributes-in-server-controls/

Apparently it will still work with the HTML encoding, which makes sense, though I've not tested this myself.

Comment: I would like to just say my composite control that was encoding the values, worked despite being encoded. So my solution was that I didn't realise that composite control handled the encoded apostrophes correctly.